# Autodesk Forge Data Exchange API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm following the https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/fdx/v1/tutorials/1_access_exchange_container/ tutorial.
I've run the curl 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/'$PROJECT_ID'/folders/'$FOLDER_ID'/contents' --header 'Authorization: Bearer '$TOKEN command to get the id of the item with type of items:autodesk.bim360:FDX

```html
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "items",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:9k_QlS2qQTuBZaBiiBKcHQ",
            "attributes": {
                ...
                "extension": {
                    "type": "items:autodesk.bim360:FDX",
```

However, when I'm trying to get the data exchange container using the curl 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/exchange/v1/exchanges?filters=attribute.exchangeFileUrn=='$ITEM_ID --header 'Authorization: Bearer '$TOKEN with the ITEM_ID I've got earlier, I'm getting the "The client_id specified does not have access to the api product" error.
The app has been provisioned to use the Data Exchange API.

Do you know if there is specific access to this API that needs to be requested?

Answer (score 3):

When creating the Forge App, make sure that the Data Exchange API is selected as shown bellow:

[image]

If you already have a Forge App created, you'll have to edit it, to enable the Data Exchange API, by clicking "EDIT" button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @denis-grigor but my app is already provisioned to use the Data Exchange API

Answer (score 2):

Created a new app, authenticated with a different account with an active subscription and now the old app works as well.